# git pull fails in 75% of cases when 20 attempts made at once

Tags: git

I have a central server and when I need to do a batch task I launch a number of AWS instances simultaneously.  During startup they call git pull (master is the central server) to get their version of the codebase up to head, so I often have 20 (or many more) pull requests at once.

Recently the delta between the instance's starting image and head has become fairly large, and now a large percentage of the instances will have the pull fail with:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can alleviate the issue by staggering the launching of the instances and keeping their image closer to head, but I would like to solve this issue for good - any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the ssh server limiting the number of connections. What OS is on the central server? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127077/number-of-ssh-connections-on-a-single-linux-machine

Comment: Amazon Linux...

Comment: /etc/security/limits.conf is empty though (well, just a load of comments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are hitting both `MaxSessions` and `MaxStartups` limits.
Edit your [/etc/sshd_config](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) to this values and it will work after you reload sshd config.

```
# The number of simultaneous git pull you have
MaxSessions 20  

# MaxStartups this tells when sshd will start dropping unauthencicated sessions (% drop)
# Values: When_to_start_dropping_sessions:initial_rate:max_unauthenticated_sessions
# Set to MaxSessions-2*MaxSession:10:HugeNumber (defaults to 10:30:100).

MaxStartups 40:10:200
```

Comment: About to try this - it's /etc/ssh/sshd_config on this linux distro fyi

Comment: Also worth adding to the answer that after editing this file we need sudo service sshd restart

Comment: I take that previous comment back - it seems to have increased the maxconnections without me restarting the service